# Selenium and OSX - Automate system prompts

Tags: python, macos, selenium

So far I was not able to find a way to automate button pressing or selection on system panels from OSX.

I use Selenium to automate the browser app, but if I need to load/save or do any action that involve interact with standard OSX system panels, I can't interact with them.
While digging in the Selenium docs, I found that they are out of the scope of Selenium API, which explain why I can't access them. How do I actually run a Selenium script and solve the issue, pressing on buttons or use save/load views? I am using selenium in conjunction with Python3.

To be specific; I would like to know if there is a way to get

- Is the OS showing a system panel? What is its name?
- Is the system pane a yes/no type or a load/save type?

The main issue here is to figure out what am I dealing with (save/load, overwrite prompt and so on), so I can at least automate partially, using mouse coordinates and trigger keyboard or click events.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like AutoIt or Automator

Comment: Would they work in conjunction with Selenium? Or do I have to use Popen to start a subprocess to handle the OS system panels, and then bring back control to the Selenium process?

Comment: I would do it the other way. Start python from them

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time I was using Selenium too. I remember that there is a feature which can locate the cursor to any coordinate where you want. You can check [Selenium Library](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/selenium-python/latest/selenium-python.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the cursor capabilities; although I have to tell Selenium what to look for, and there is no way to query the OS and ask "is it a button" or "is it a textfield". I can assume that at one point in time, something will happen and I will click on a specific location, but that is not really ideal for writing tests.